# Loading an array stored in a text file in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

Without using jquery mobile or other framework what the most efficient way to load two dimensional string data from a text file in the /www dictionary into an javascript array in phonegap?

If it matters, feel also free what kind of formatting for the text file is the best.

I tried:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("GET", "/android_asset/data.txt");

request.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    console.log("* data.txt1 " );

    if (request.readyState == 4) {

        console.log("*" + request.responseText + "* data.txt2" );

    }
};

request.send();
```

It gives me the error:

> [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///android_asset/data.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (0)

Comment: you can use the native browsers/Webview(in case of phonegap) `XMLHttpRequest` specifying the path of the file in the arguments. Then parse the loaded data depending whether is is JSON, XML, CSV or any format that you are expecting it to be.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using cordova, why not use the native file system support provided. Below code should work for both iOS and android.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
            fs.root.getFile("../myapp/www/content/" + "words.txt", null, function(fe)
            {
                fe.file(function(f) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                        // do sth with the reader.result data    
                        console.log(reader.result);
                    }
                    reader.readAsText(f);
                }, fail);
            }, fail);
        }, fail);
```

fail is just a callback for handling failure cases in the above code.

Comment: I get the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined" while testing on Android

Comment: did you add the file plugin?

Comment: Cordova File plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: in my case the path was `www/some file name`. i didn't need to type the app name